# Alternating Series in Normed Vector Spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, normed-spaces

We know this fact from elementary calculus: the series $\sum (-1)^na_n$ converges for all positive sequence $(a_n)$ such that $a_n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

I come upon a similar result which I still have not successfully proven yet.

Let $H: V \to V$ be a bounded linear transformation from a normed vector space $V$ to itself. Assume also that $\| H\|<1.$ Then for each $v\in V$, we can easily see that $$\sum_{n}(-1)^n\|H^nv\|$$ converges. How does that implies that $$\sum_{n}(-1)^nH^nv$$ also converges?

Any hint or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Counterexample to the assertion in the first paragraph:
$a_{2n} = 2/(n + 1),$ $a_{2n+1} = 1/(n + 1)$ ($n = 0, 1, 2,
\ldots$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, for this question to be answerable, you need the space $V$ to be Banach, because otherwise it is entirely possible that the infinite series converges to some vector which *ought* to exist, but doesn't because you're working in too small a vector space. Basically, whenever you want to prove a limit exists, but you don't know what value the limit should converge to, you're usually going to need to have some completeness condition on your space, since if you don't know what the limit ought to be, the only easy way to get convergence is to show your sequence is Cauchy.

It would be difficult to try and go from some conditionally convergent series of norms to a conditionally convergent series of vectors. However, we don't have to! Note that $\sum_n ||H^nv||$ in fact converges absolutely, since $||H^nv|| \leq ||H||^n \cdot ||v||,$ and $||H|| < 1,$ so that this series is bounded above by a convergent geometric series.

Therefore, the series $\sum_n (-1)^nH^nv$ converges, since $\sum_n ||(-1)^nH^nv|| = \sum_n ||H^nv||$ converges.

If you've not seen the last statement, here's a quick proof that if $\sum_n ||v_n||$ converges, then so does $\sum_n v_n,$ for $v_n$ vectors in a Banach space. Let $S_N = \sum_{n=1}^N v_n$ be the partial sums. Then $S_N$ is a Cauchy sequence of vectors, because
$$|S_N - S_M| \leq \sum_{n=N+1}^M ||v_n||,$$
and we know that $\sum_n ||v_n||$ is convergent, so that its partial sums are Cauchy. Therefore, $S_N$ is a Cauchy sequence in a Banach space, so it must converge.